# Incorrect pagination UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Created a UICollectionView with a horizontal scroll in which the cells occupy the entire width of the screen. Set the isPagingEnabled flag to true. But for some reason, the cell scrolls on the iPad mini is not quite correct, it is not centered.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How do you define "entire width of the screen" ?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).